# copy/paste multiple lines or line by line from site

Tags: command-line

Simple question not a problem.  If I am on a site like 'ask ubuntu' and looking to install a program, instead of using GUI, I just follow the CLI instructions.  Sometimes they might have three or four lines, I copy/paste each line separately, is this the best or could I copy all lines as one block, then paste.  I use fish shell and don't think it likes &&.  Just wondering, thank you. An example `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:appgrid/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install appgrid` Shows up a code box.

Answer (score 2):

Make a text file and copy all lines there. Let's call it `lines.txt`

Then execute all commands of that file via

```
bash lines.txt
```

Comment: Run `bash -eu` to let the script fail on error or unset variables.

Comment: So I am right to just copy/paste single line at a time, unless I want to do more work.  Most of this is only single use, not likely to be used again.   Remember I usually have to look up how to do most CLI stuff, unless it is simple copy/paste without having to add/change stuff.

Comment: Doing it line-by-line is fine - usually it is only 3-5 lines anyway. What this solution does is the very same thing: instead of letting `bash` execute every line separately and by hand, you just make it execute one after the other - it just reads it from the textfile. Of course the textfile can be deleted in the end.

Comment: Thanks, now I will google how to make a text file,  thanks for your help.

Comment: To create a file with some lines from pasting:  Run `cat > lines.txt`, then paste the lines, press `enter`, `ctrl+d`. Done.

Answer (score 2):

You can paste the commands in a subshell and add `set -eu` to make it fail on error and unset variables (or maybe better `set -euo pipefail`):

Start a subshell with typing `(`, end with `)`, like this:

```
$ ( set -eu # press enter
> Paste multiple
> lines of code
> ) # press enter to run.
```

or similarly, run `bash -euc 'multiple lines of code'` like this:

```
$ bash -euc ' # press enter
> paste multiple
> lines of code
> ' # press enter
```

> Disclaimer: Do not paste anything of which you're not 100% sure what it does. Some people here even say you should not paste anything at all, but type it by yourself.

Comment: Will this work with 'fish shell' for first suggestion and for second can I just change 'bash' to 'fish'

Comment: `fish` can do `-c`, and it can do `-n` (only do syntax checking) which might be good option to do first. Not sure about `-e` and `-u`.

Comment: Thank you, basically just wanted to know if a code box/block was good to copy as whole or to do it line by line.  It is good to know there are other ways of doing it, but for now I will stick with the line by line.  It is nice and safe for me.